# get attribute of ActiveRecord object by string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It is probably a really simple thing but can't find a solution.

I have an ActiveRecord object and want to get an attribute like this:

```
attribute_name = "name"
user = User.find(1)
user.get_attribute_by_name(attribute_name) => "John"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

All of these should work:

```
user[attribute_name]
user.read_attribute(attribute_name)
user.send(attribute_name)
```

Personally I wouldn't use `send` in this case. When available, prefer `public_send` to send

Comment: I concur that it is better to avoid `send`. However if you are accessing an association rather than a plain attribute, it seems like `send` is your best bet.

Comment: Can you tell me why I should avoid `send`? I'm afraid I have to use it.

Comment: @user2041318 with send you need to be extra sure that you've been passed an actual attribute name (rather than, for example, 'destroy')

Comment: If there's a wrapper plugin over the attribute (like, carrierwave), first two solutions will get u string instead of Carrierwave object. If  u want attribute including wrapper class, use this
`user.read_attribute_for_serialization(attribute_name)`
(it works, though I dont know what that fuction is for)

Comment: how can i extract one column from list of objects? Example userslist is the list of objects of your and i want to extract firstnames of all users

Comment: `user[attribute_name]` are different `user.send(attribute_name)`. `user[attr_name]` => get from db field, `user.send(attr_name)` => get from model

Answer (score 9):

You can use either `[]` or `read_attribute()` but [they are not equivalent](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide/issues/155). 
 The safer method of access is using the [[] method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/%5B%5D) method because it will raise an `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` error if the attribute does not exist.  The [read_attribute method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute) returns `nil` if the attribute does not exist.

Comment: The [read_attribute method is still present in ActiveRecord 5](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute) and I can't find any hints about it being deprecated.

Comment: Read [this APIdock page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/read_attribute) which states the following: _"This method is deprecated or moved on the latest stable version. The last existing version (v2.3.8) is shown here."_

Comment: It was just moved to the module `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Read` and is still present.

Comment: I removed the notes about the function being deprecated and added some new notes on the differences between the `[]` and `read_attribute` functions.

Answer (score -2):

In Rails 5, just `attribute_name = "name"` works