# Rails: How to access attributes of my @results object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controller

Having tried to access the 'answer1' attribute on my @results object via:

```
@results.answer1
```

...I looked online, and tried the solutions suggested here...
[get attribute of ActiveRecord object by string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808949/get-attribute-of-activerecord-object-by-string)
..but I can't seem to access the attributes of my passed ActiveRecord @results object.

Initially the user is directed to the /quizzes/new view, the QuizzesController#new action which looks like this:

```
def new
        @user = current_user
        @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers.build
    end
```

@quiz_answer is, therefore accessible to the view and passed into the form_for there. **EDIT:** Here is my form (a partial rendered as part of quizzes/new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for(@quiz_answer) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer1) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer2) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer3) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer4) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer5) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer6) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer7) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer8) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When the user clicks submit on the form the QuizAnswers#create action is triggered which redirects to results_path (the index action in the ResultsController).

@results is therefore accessible to the view because of the index action in ResultsController:

```
def index
    # in order to access all the results in our view...
    @results = current_user.quiz_answers
  end
```

In my results/index view, this

```
<p><%= @results %></p>
```

outputs the following to the page:

```
#<QuizAnswer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x5191b30>
```

...so the object is not nil.

But when I try to access the 'answer1' attribute of @results, via:

```
<p><%= @results[answer1] %></p>
```

**OR**

```
<p><%= @results.read_attribute(answer1) %></p>
```

...I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `answer1' for #<#<Class:0x72384d8>:0x71b6d10>
```

Finally, in my routes.rb, I define the following reources:

```
resources :quizzes
  resources :results  
  resources :quiz_answers

  resources :users do
    resources :posts

  end
```

But when I include 'resources :quiz_answers' as part of 'resources :user' (immediately below the 'resources :posts' line) I get the following error:

```
undefined method `quiz_answers_path' for #<#<Class:0x5310618>:0x5411b80>
```

...when I go to the quizzes/new page.

So my question is: If quiz_answers needs to be a resource included as part of the user resource, how do I pass current_user.quiz_answers to form_for? And if it DOESN'T need to be 'part of' the user resource, how do I access the attributes of quiz_answers?

Once again, if there's anything I'm presuming or doing wrong, please feel free to explain the 'Rails way' of doing it.

**EDIT**

I think I've been asked for the models, controllers and migration, so here you go:

users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = current_user
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to(@user)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is just a good pattern
    # since you'll be able to reuse the same permit list between create and update. Also, you
    # can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :age, :email, :section)
    end
end
```

quiz answers controller:

```
class QuizAnswersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = current_user
        @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers.build
    end

    def create 
        redirect_to results_path
    end

    private 

    def post_params
        params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:body, :user_id)
    end
end
```

results controller:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # in order to access all the results in our view...
    @results = current_user.quiz_answers
  end
end
```

schema.rb (let me know if this is what you need, migration-wise):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141002130233) do

  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"

  create_table "quiz_answers", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "answer1"
    t.string   "answer2"
    t.string   "answer3"
    t.string   "answer4"
    t.string   "answer5"
    t.string   "answer6"
    t.string   "answer7"
    t.string   "answer8"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "quiz_answers", ["user_id"], name: "index_quiz_answers_on_user_id"

# Could not dump table "users" because of following NoMethodError
#   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

end
```

And the QuizAnswer model:

```
class QuizAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

end
```

The User model is pretty long, but it DOES include:

```
has_many :posts
has_many :quiz_answers
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: try <p><%= @results["answer1"] %></p>

Comment: I get the error 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer'. But thanks for trying...

Comment: Sorry if @results is ActiveRecord object and it has answer1 attribute, try `@results.answer1`

Comment: If it still raise error, to confirm things, can you show `<%= @results.inspect %>` output?

Comment: Sorry - should have said, but the FIRST thing I tried (before looking online) was (AT)results.answer1, where '(AT)' = '@' (Can't include more than 1 (AT) symbol in a comment). (AT)results.inspect outputs: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: `@results.first.attribbute`? I believe `@results.first` is an instance of a model.

Comment: @results.first.attribute generates the error 'undefined method `attribute' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: He means @results.first.answer1

Comment: @results.first generates the <p></p> tags in the html but doesn't render anything between them, I guess confirming that it's nil.

Comment: Similarly, @results.first.answer1 generates the error "undefined method `answer1' for nil:NilClass". I think (AT)results.first is nil...

Comment: of course generates `@results.first.attribute generates` the error. could you show us the models `User`, and `QuizAnswer`?

Comment: there might be something else wrong here, gist the controller and model and the migraton

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ; I'm still a newbie that's trying anything to make it work. If you have a solution, that would be great!

Comment: @moosefetcher ok, so `current_user.quiz_answers` shell return answers relation, i.e. that answer that belongs to user. then if you issue `current_user.quiz_answers.size`, it should tell you length of answers array.

Comment: current_user.quiz_answers.size returns 0. So the answer1 attribute hasn't been set? I'll add my form above. Please let me know if the various answer1, answer2 attributes are set up correctly or not...

Comment: if `current_user.quiz_answers.size` is zero so the user has no answers, and you can use answer1 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the comments are perfectly valid i.e. you are setting an CollectionProxy to the variable `@results` but your main issue is that the `create` action in your QuizAnswersController does *nothing* except redirect to `results_path`.

Although Rails will do a lot of work for you, you have to process the parameters which are submitted by your form in the `create` action.

There's quite a lot in issue with your code here so I'd suggest you read [this part of the Rails Guide on Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters). You'll also need to adjust the `post_params` method in your QuizAnswersController as you only permit the `body` and `user_id` attributes to be mass-assigned meaning you won't be able to do anything with the `answer1` etc. attributes unless you assign them manually.

Having said that, what do they do in the form? As far as I can see, they will just be checkboxes setting a true or false value?

Your QuizAnswersController needs to look something like this.

```
class QuizAnswersController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers.new(post_params) #from private method
    if @quiz_answer.save
      redirect_to results_path
    else
      #error handle here
    end
  end

  private 

  def post_params
    params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:answer1, :answer2) #add other attributes here
  end
end
```

EDIT: You say you are permitting a `body` attribute on the QuizAnswer model but that's not one of its attributes according to your DB schema so I've updated the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said in the comments, I'm still a newbie so all of this is news to me. It still seems like there's a lot to think about simultaneously to do something simple; The post_params method was just copied from my User model. I'll let you know how the improvements work out.

Comment: Completely understand. We were all there once.

Comment: At the moment I'm just including the answer1, 2, text attributes in the form as check boxes. I just want to test something as simply as possible (I can't believe that the huge question I've had to ask is as 'simple as possible', but that's Rails, I guess).

Comment: Gah! I've updated my QuizAnswersController exactly as you've detailed, but I still get the error "undefined method `answer1' for #<QuizAnswer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x4ae7940>" from <p><%= @results.answer1 %></p>. Thanks for the reply. If you have any other pointers, I'd been keen to hear them.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean in the EDIT part of your answer. Where am I permitting a body attribute on the QuizAnswer model? Did you mean the code I had in my previous version of QuizAnswerController, in the post_params method?

Comment: OK, well I've got a version working; A combination of your create method (which I think still ADDs a quiz_answers instance to User as opposed to updating the one that's present) and an altered version of @Малъ Скрылевъ's solution. In my QuizzesController I now check current_user.quiz_answers.size. If it's >0 (ie, an instance has been added) it triggered the results view (because the user has already done the quiz) and if it's 0, it does (AT)quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers.build. Does that seem sensible? Ideally I'd like NOT to ADD an instance of quiz_answers but perhaps this will do.

Comment: I should add that, when current_user.quiz_answers.size > 0, I set @results = current_user.quiz_answers.last and redirect_to results_path. Малъ Скрылевъ's solution - to print out multiple quiz_answers - made it clear to me that a new group of 8 answers (with its own answer1-8 attributes) were being added each time a User did the quiz.

Answer (score 0):

Since `@results` is a relation that includes all `quiz_answer`s that belong to the current user:

```
@results = current_user.quiz_answers
```

your **results/index.erb** view will contain something like:

```
<%- @results.each do |quiz_answer| %>
   <%# ... some code shows answer data like %>
   <h4>Quiz Answer</h4>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer1 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer2 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer3 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer4 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer5 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer6 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer7 %></p>
   <p><%= quiz_answer.answer8 %></p>
<%- end %>
```

If no `quiz_answer`s are assigned to the current user, that form will be skipped in output. And probably you should add `name` field to `quiz_answer` table then you can add it to above form as:

```
   <p>Name: <%= quiz_answer.name %></p>
```

To assign the newly created `quiz_answer` add to `create` action inside the `QuizAnswersController` assignment to the current user, like follows:

```
class QuizAnswersController < ApplicationController
   def create 
      quiz_answer = QuizAnswer.create(params.require(:quiz_answer).permit(:answer1)
      current_user.quiz_answers << quiz_answer
      redirect_to results_path
      # require 'pry'
      # binding.pry
   end
end
```

After the `quiz_answer.save!` please make sure that the `current_user.quiz_answers` isn't empty by checking its `#size`. You can debug your it by using `pry` gem. Just add it to **Gemfile**, then insert to required place as a breakpoint, and uncomment the two lines with `require`, and `binding`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is outputting, but each time I complete the form it adds another 'set' of QuizAnswers (I assume adding them to the current_user). Do you know why that is happening? Is there something that's adding a new QuizAnswers as opposed to dealing with the current_user.quiz_answers?

Comment: @moosefetcher that is because you are not assigning the quiz_answer in the create/update operation to current user

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, sorry. Which controller and which action needs to assign quiz_answer? Thanks...

Comment: Thanks again. But it doesn't seem to like the initialize method in the create action. I get the error: private method `initialize' called for #<Class:0x4ffaa00>

Comment: @moosefetcher sorry my mistake, thay should be `::create`, and no `#save` method is required. I've updated the post

Comment: Is it create or ::create? Either way, I'm back to getting the error: undefined method `answer1' for nil:NilClass. I might have to come back to this tomorrow. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66674/discussion-between---and-moosefetcher).