# rails method as a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This has probably been asked before but I cannot find any info on this

I am using I18n with 2 locales en and ja

Trying to fetch data from a table that has columns like title_en title_ja. So when locale is en title_en should be shown

Is there a short way to do this in ruby?

I am trying to use helpers:

```
module WorksHelper
    def col_lang(col)
        if (locale == :ja)
            lang = "_ja"
        else
            lang = "_en"
        end
        return col+lang
    end
end
```

And then I cant figure out a way to call this in the views. I am trying this:

```
<%= work.(col_lang("title")) %>
```

but obviously this is wrong. Ruby says `undefined method call` . How do I call the function here?

Comment: View helpers are available directly, e.g., `<%= col_lang("language" %>`. The function *could* be written as `"#{col}#{locale == :ja ? '_ja' : '_en'"`. If it's not a view helper, and it's just a utility class, then the answer from spickermann is correct.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just used this for something else on the website, and it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line in the view to:

```
<%= work.send(col_lang("title")) %>
```

**Or** (because IMO it is easier to read) change the helper to:

```
module WorksHelper
  def localized_attribute(instance, attribute)
    suffix = (locale == :ja) ? 'ja' : 'en'
    instance.send("#{attribute}_#{suffix}")
  end
end
```

and call it in your view like this:

```
<%= localized_attribute(work, :title) %>
```

Comment: Thank you! Need to wait before i can choose this as an answer apparently, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to define a method in your model:

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def title(locale = I18n.locale)
    public_send(:"title_#{locale}")
  end
end
```

And call it via:

```
<%= work.title %>
```

or, to specify a locale explicitly:

```
<%= work.title(:ja) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, what you're trying to do is to fetch a model's attribute by a string containing its name, rather than the symbol representation.

[This is how you do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808949/get-attribute-of-activerecord-object-by-string)

Ideally, you should avoid using `send`, as spickermann's answer recommends, because `send` will also let you send a `destroy` command without realising it. Not ideal. Try using `read_attribute` instead:

```
module WorksHelper
  def localized_attribute(instance, attribute)
    suffix = (locale == :ja) ? 'ja' : 'en'
    instance.read_attribute("#{attribute}_#{suffix}")
  end
end
```